# HTML to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have a NSString flood of HTML special characters, there is a way to gain the text like when the page is visualized on a browser? Or I must convert it from php?

Comment: By special characters do you mean `&...;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only text from an HTML page that can contain all sorts of things, it's probably best to [use WebKit to walk the DOM](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/DOMObjCBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001206-BCIGCAIE) and extract the text from interesting elements. The docs are a little anemic here, but now that you know a good mechanism, it's far easier to find specific examples on the web.